# Is there anyway to solve this without using two for loop

Tags: python

This is problem from my assignment in college

I have list(n elements) of tuple(2 elements = ID, text)

for example:

```
data = [('user1', 'text1'), ('user2', 'text1'),...]
```

and i want to find frequency of pair of 'ID' that have same 'text'

for example:

```
data = [('user1', 'text1'), ('user2', 'text1'), ('user3', 'text1'), 
        ('user1', 'text2'), ('user2', 'text2'), ('user3', 'text2')]
frequency = {('user1', 'user2'): 2, ('user1', 'user3'): 2, ('user2', 'user3'): 2}
```

(pairs are ascending 'ID' from least to most)

```
only ('user1','user2')
not ('user2','user1')
```

but the multiple same 'text' with same pair will count as one.

for example:

```
data = [('user1', 'text1'), ('user2', 'text1'), ('user1', 'text1'), ('user2', 'text1')]
```

will result in

```
frequency = {('user1', 'user2'): 1}
```

here are my codes

```
def somefunction(data):
    sametext = {}
    for element in data:
        if element[1] in sametext:
            if element[0] not in sametext[element[1]]:
                sametext[element[1]].append(element[0])
        else:
            sametext[element[2]] = [element[1]]
    frequency = {}
    for ID in sametext.values():
        ID.sort()
        index = 1
        for x1 in ID:
            for x2 in ID[index:]:
                pair = (x1, x2)
                if pair in frequency:
                    frequency[pair] += 1
                else:
                    frequency[pair] = 1
            index += 1
    return frequency
```

I store 'ID' which have same text in dictionary to smaller the loop, but it isn't enough.

With data size of 1 million element, it took more than 1 min.

Is there a way to make this faster?

Thank for every comment

Comment: If the run time is really important (rather than the 'efficiency' of the code) you could use a brute force approach and use the multiprocessing module to run this across as many virtual cores as you have available. The effectiveness of this will depend how many cores you have and what OS you are using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, mainly because you are using a list, use a set, like below:

```
from collections import defaultdict, Counter
from itertools import combinations

data = [('user1', 'text1'), ('user2', 'text1'), ('user3', 'text1'),
        ('user1', 'text2'), ('user2', 'text2'), ('user3', 'text2')]


def fun(d):
    # group users by text
    groups = defaultdict(set)
    for user, text in d:
        groups[text].add(user)

    # compute the frequencies
    # combinations is going to generate the pair interactions
    counts = Counter(tuple(sorted(pair)) for v in groups.values() for pair in combinations(v, 2))

    # convert to dictionary (the call to dict is optional)
    return dict(counts)


frequencies = fun(data)

print(frequencies)
```

**Output**

```
{('user1', 'user2'): 2, ('user2', 'user3'): 2, ('user1', 'user3'): 2}
```

Containment queries in list are `O(n)` vs in set that are `O(1)` in average. See also the documentation on [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) and [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict).

Comment: I tried this, but it still slow.
I had test time, the upper part where I use list is very fast.
The main bottleneck is lower part, where I use nested loop.
Thanks for advice anyway.

Comment: And I curious. Containment queries in list are slower, but adding elements to set are slower. Isn't time still nearly the same?

Comment: Not at all, adding at element to a set is also O(1) in average but is true that the constants are higher, but no the time is not the same. List will only be faster if there are few elements in it.

Comment: BTW is this faster or not than your function?

Comment: this is faster but only a little

Comment: Can you tell me what is the average size of the list in `sametext` ?

Comment: 90% are one. Others are 2-50

Comment: https://www.cp.eng.chula.ac.th/~somchai/2110101/2563-1/ProgHW/tweet_info.zip
here are data set. import using this. 
    f = open(filename)
    data = [tuple(line.strip().split(',')[1:3])
              for line in f.readlines()]
    f.close()